# How to set start position of element after dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, phaser-framework

I have an element which must be dragged. Also it is important to set start coordinates to this element after it's dragged.

So, I do like this, but nothing happens at all

Also the coordinates stay the same after dragging and I wonder why it is so

At first I used the ...body.x and so on, but nothing happend too, maybe I do something wrong?

```
var droid;

var someObj = {

   START_X: '',
   START_Y: '', 
   init: function() {
     droid = game.add.sprite(profile.x - 240, profile.y + 150, 'droid', profileGroup);
     droid.fixedToCamera = true;
     droid.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);

     this.initPhysics();
   },

   startDrag: function() {
    console.log('start'); 
    droid.body.moves = false;  
    this.START_X = droid.x;
    this.START_Y = droid.y;
    droid.z = 200;
    console.log('********START*******');
    console.log(droid); 
    console.log('DROID = ',droid.x, droid.y);
    console.log('START = ',this.START_X, this.START_Y);
   },

   stopDrag: function() {
    droid.body.moves = true;   
    droid.x = this.START_X;
    droid.y = this.START_Y;
    droid.z = 75;
    console.log('********STOP*******');
    console.log(droid); 
    console.log('DROID = ',droid.x, droid.y);
    console.log('END = ',this.START_X, this.START_Y);
   },

  initPhysics: function() {
    console.log('create');
    game.physics.arcade.enable(droid);
    droid.inputEnabled = true;
    droid.input.enableDrag();

    droid.events.onDragStart.add(this.startDrag, this);
    droid.events.onDragStop.add(this.stopDrag, this);
 }
}
```

Couldn't you help me to solve this problem?

I will really appreciate that!

Thank you!

Comment: It'd be easier to solve if you add a fiddle.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? You should at least share what is traced in the console, ideally make a jsfiddle like tkay suggested.

Comment: @MarwaneK.A. it shows that the coords stay the same. For example: DROID = 10, 10; START = 10, 10; and then DROID = 10, 10; START = 10, 10;